# I want to create a (non mathematical) matrix of features

Tags: tables

I'm trying to get a comparative matrix of features, like attached.

For the life of me I can't find a LaTeX package combination to make this work.

- I need square cells
- that I can colour
- with tight, slanted headings

Basically, I have lots of data I need to see at a glance and I can't figure out what combination of various table packages (tabular, tabularx, tablu), colour and other things works to pull this off.

[image]

Comment: Yes? all of the above.

Comment: there are lots and lots of table packages, and i end up with horrible messes when i try and square cells; colourized, and slanted headings working together.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

- In order to have square cells, fix the width of the columns to 8 mm (and set `tabcolsep` which is the length on both sides of a column to 0 pt) and put a strut of total height 8 mm in each row (`\rule[-3mm]{0pt}{8mm}`).
- Use `\rotatebox` of `graphicx` to rotate the contents of each cell of the first row.
- In `{NiceTabular}`, the key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the 'first row' and the 'first column' (specified by the corresponding keys).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MyRotate}{m}
  {  \rotatebox[origin=c]{80}{#1} }

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}[first-row,first-col,hvlines,colortbl-like,columns-width=8mm]
     {>{\rule[-3mm]{0pt}{8mm}}ccccc}
    & \MyRotate{Feature A}
    & \MyRotate{Feature B}
    & \MyRotate{Feature C}
    & \MyRotate{Feature 1}
    & \MyRotate{Feature 2} \\
Foo & & \cellcolor{blue!15} & & \cellcolor{red!15}{}\\
Bar & & \cellcolor{blue!15} & \cellcolor{blue!15} & \cellcolor{red!15} & \cellcolor{red!15}\\
Baz & \cellcolor{blue!15}\\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

*Remark*: With `nicematrix`, you will have a good output in all PDF viewers at all levels of zoom.